# Execute your own php functions at the time of the event reminder in google calendar api

Tags: php, ionic-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created a sports application which is used to program sports events with date and time. One hour before each event, this app must notify users to remind them of the event.

I created notifications and functions to list users and events but I could not create a system to execute these functions at the exact time.

I tried several days to find a solution especially with cronjobs and I could not.

Then I was reading about the Google calendar api and I noticed that in the first versions you could run external functions at the time of notifications.

**My question is: *¿Is it possible to execute your own php functions at the time of the event reminder in google calendar api?***

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You should post your attempt that used cron.  This would be the way to go.

Comment: I already gave up with cron jobs because what I did was execute a function every 10 seconds and this caused the server to become saturated. That's why I'm looking for other alternatives (Google Calendar Api) or a type of scheduling tasks that runs at the exact time.

Comment: I feel like precision on the order of a minute would be adequate for something like this, no?  If your sever can't handle running a task every minute, then you need a new server.  Even once every 10 seconds is not that much.  I'll reiterate that this is the way to go.  However, if you are dead set on using Google Calendar, you could start a mail server on your server, parse incoming emails, and trigger the desired action when you receive the notification email from Google.  That's going to be a _lot_ more work though.

Comment: Totally agree. I thought about executing the function every second but I do not know what problems it would bring for the server since it would generate several events in queue since I have to notify the mobile phones of all the users that participate in said event. But if you think that this way I can solve it and that it would not cause any problems, I will do it this way while someone answers about the Google calendar api.

Comment: I wonder if https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push would help. It's not clear to me just from reading that whether it notifies you when it's the time for the reminder or not, or whether it's only when someone actually modifies the event, but perhaps you can experiment. The only other way to get reminder notifications which might be readable by your server is by email (see https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders).

Comment: The other approach you could take is simply to make a request to the API and ask it to return you events which occur in the next hour, and then send out your reminders for all those events via your app. It seems this might be simpler than trying to hook into Google's reminder system.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke directly with someone in google and in the public and private documentation of their api there is no way to do that. I found the solution with cronjobs executing them through the database and doing a function that covers the difference in minutes. It works perfectly. Thank you very much